# Proxy-ing a SOAP server

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, soap

I need to communicate with a httpS SOAP server on a different port than the standard 443. The client app doesn't work (because of restrictions) with different ports than the standard ones for HTTP and HTTPS

How can I setup my linux server running Apache to tunnel all these requests coming in at soap.domain.com to https://soapserver.otherdomain.com:1234/Service.asmx ?

Answer (score 1):

A reverse proxy will help you.

You can use apache mod_proxy to help you. By using mod_proxy apache will receive the request on the standard HTTP/HTTPS ports and then internally redirect it to the SOAP server.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Read up on reverse proxy. It will help you understand better.

Comment: Thanks, but is it going to be a problem that I will be running this through a self-signed SSL certificate on the proxy?

Comment: That won't be a problem!  Remember that specifying HTTPS without a port in a URL says two things.  One, that you're using a secure channel.  Two, that you're using port 443.  By specifying an alternate port, you're still using an encrypted stream.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a reverse proxy such as [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) with `proxy_pass` option.

Both will allow you to proxy requests to upstream servers and both will allow HTTPS to soap.domain.com and allow proxying to an encrypted HTTPS upstream server in your case: https://soapserver.otherdomain.com:1234/Service.asmx

In my experience nginx is the somewhat easier to setup and configure.

An appropriate nginx configuration may resemble the following:

```
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  soap.domain.com;
ssl_certificate     soap.domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key soap.domain.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://soapserver.otherdomain.com:1234;                     
}
```

And yes, you can use a self signed certificate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear where you need to do this - on the SOAP client? On the SOAP server? somewhere in between? The approach is the same regardless - there are multiple ways of doing this.

- You could use iptables to rewrite the packet addresses.
- Run a packet proxy daemon (e.g. netcat) to listen on port 443 and connect to port XXX
- Configure [x]inetd to listen on port 443 and run a generic socket client (e.g. netcat again) connecting to port XXX

The first method would allow you to preserve the client address seen by the server.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this; I need to do this in between, since the SOAP client is unable to connect to a different port than the standard available ones and the SOAP server is beyond my control and is running on another port. So therefore I have a need to place one in the middle that basically just answers the requests from the client to (https)soap.serverinthemiddle.com with the actual answer of (https)soap.server.com:1234/Service.asmx

Comment: You probably don't need a seperate machine - all three approaches would work deployed on either the client or the server - but since I assume that the soap service runs on a MSWindows box, it's rather difficult to implement there.